# are there any ad blockers for IE8?

Tags: browser-addons, internet-explorer-8, adblock

Firefox and Chrome have Adblock.

Does anything similar exist for IE8?

By *similar* I mean:

- Easy to install
- Trusted (that is, reviewed by somebody credible)
- updates easily

Answer (score 1):

Adblock IE may be something that appeals to you

http://adblockie.codeplex.com/

Comment: I've been looking at Adblock IE, but it doesn't seem to do anything. It installs, and then...nothing. Do you know how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than installing software or some add on, here is a non invasive way to block anything you want on any browser in Windows

http://www.mvps.org/winhelp2002/hosts.htm

.

Comment: I've seen this before, but the only problem is that it is hard for beginners to figure out, and requires knowledge of advertising sites and such...Installing an adblocker takes care of this problem and saves us time and effort.

Comment: @studioshack, they provide ad block lists, its not as hard as it seems, besides they may Learn something along the way.

Comment: This doesn't meet the "easy to install" requirement

Comment: It was easy for me?

Answer (score 0):

I use [AdThwart](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb?) for Chrome, is that any worse?

Comment: does it work on IE?

Answer (score 0):

K9 Web Protection is a child's (or children's) web filtering and blocking software that is extremely configurable. You could turn off all the settings that you didn't want (filtering, word block, site block, category block, time limits/restrictions), and **just use advertisement block feature.**  It works cross-browsers; one configuration covers Internet Explorer, Firefox, and others all one the same machine.

K9 Web Protection: http://www1.k9webprotection.com/

Did I mention that it is FREE?  Highly recommend and does the job well.

For Windows only, and works very well.  Installs separately - not as an addon, and all configurations are protected by a password...